# Hot to catch a websocket-close event when client changes IP address or disconnects?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, websocket, netty

I'm developing an application using web-sockets. The server side is written in Java and uses Netty as application framework, while the client is written in javascript/jquery. I'd like to catch any kind of client disconnection, but actually I can do that only when the client goes to a different website or just reload the page of the application. Contrary, if clients changes IP on-the-fly or disables the network interface (wireless or ethernet), the close event is only caught by client, but not server. Is there a way to catch also this kind of close event without using ping messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send PING/PONG to actually detect if a peers go down.

Comment: I would have liked to avoid that mainly because javascript doesn't have any implementation, but ok... if it's the only solution.